# Hi im getting a EOF error with this how do i correct this?

Tags: eof

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

datei = open("Datei 1.txt", "r")
zeilen = datei.readlines()
zeilen.pop(0) #löscht erste Zeile
anzahl = len(zeilen)

x = []; y = [] #Leerfelder für Messwerte
for zeile in zeilen: #zeilen ist Liste aus mehreren zeile Objekten
    werte = zeile.split() #zerlegt Zeilen am Standard-Trennzeichen
    x.append(float(werte[0]))
    y.append(float(werte[1]))

    print("x = {}, y = {}".format(x[-1], y[-1])
```

Can someone explain to me hoe to get rid of the EOF - error?

Comment: you missed a parenthesis at the end of the file

Answer (score 0):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

datei = open("Datei 1.txt", "r")
zeilen = datei.readlines()
zeilen.pop(0) #löscht erste Zeile
anzahl = len(zeilen)

x = []; y = [] #Leerfelder für Messwerte
for zeile in zeilen: #zeilen ist Liste aus mehreren zeile Objekten
    werte = zeile.split() #zerlegt Zeilen am Standard-Trennzeichen
    x.append(float(werte[0]))
    y.append(float(werte[1]))

    print("x = {}, y = {}".format(x[-1], y[-1]))
```

You just forgot to add another `)` at the end of the last line.

Answer (score 0):

```
print("x = {}, y = {}".format(x[-1], y[-1])
```

This is missing the final parenthesis